# Discord py auto reaction issue

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have an event in my discord.py bot that is supposed to only react with an emoji to a message containing "welc" or "welcome", however, the bot reacts to all messages sent in the chat. Heres the code for the event.

```
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        welcome1 = 'welcome'
        welc = 'welc'
        if message.content == welcome1 or welc:
            await message.add_reaction('<:z_heart1:786021804690636810>')
```

I have tried using an else pass in my if statement but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if message.content == welcome1 or welc:` is where it's breaking. `or welc` which means if `welc` is not None and `welc` is not False. In this case `welc` has the value of `welc`

You can use a list like in my example to reduce the need for or statements.

```py
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        welcome1 = 'welcome'
        welc = 'welc'
        if message.content in [welcome1,welc]:
            await message.add_reaction('<:z_heart1:786021804690636810>')
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is, `if message.content == welcome1 or welc:` and `if message.content == welcome1 or message.content == welc:` are not the same. You can use `if message.content in [welcome1, welc]`.

```py
    welcome1 = 'welcome'
    welc = 'welc'
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        if message.content in [welcome1, welc]:
            await message.add_reaction('<:z_heart1:786021804690636810>')
```